# endless loop in until loop for unix script

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I am doing a unix script using `until loop`.The idea of my script is it need to continuously verify the url status whether is up or down.When its up, it will exit the loop. In my script, I will use `curl` for check the url status and `grep` the status code which is equal to `200` only . From what I understood how the until loop works, it will keep on execute until the condition is satisfied on we defined. When I test my script, It end up in the endless loop.
Here are my script :

```
var=""
until [echo "$var" | grep -q "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"]
do 
  var=$(curl -I -k https://mystie url | grep "HTTP/1.1 200 OK")
  echo $var
done
```

If I test the `var=$(curl -I -k https://mystie url | grep "HTTP/1.1 200 OK")` directly in the terminal, it was able to return me the correct result.

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Try to learn more about the `[` syntax using `help [` (bash only).

Comment: Which shell -- Bash ? I tried Bash 4.4.20, ksh 93u+, and dash, and they all throw a fatal error `[echo: not found`. So I suspect you are not running exactly what you posted. Or maybe hiding stderr.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant OP didn't mention the error but did mention about the endless loop

Comment: @Paul_Pedant, the error shouldn't be fatal though, and as `grep` doesn't get any input, it never finds a matching line (even if it was `grep ""`), and so the loop never ends.

Comment: still, one would hope that at least recognizing the existence of error messages (and perhaps even reading them) would be the bare minimum requirement before asking help

Comment: You omitted to mention what happenned when you ran your script and how this deviated from your expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square brackets can only contain conditional expressions (either unary or binary), therefore you need to drop the square brackets to use the exit status of your command as a condition:

```
until curl -I -k https://mystie url | grep -q "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
do
   .... do something .... 
done
```

Since you're using the square brackets incorrectly, the condition fails (and exits with non-zero status), thus your `until` loop never stops.

Square brackets (`[ ... ]`) can only contain conditional expressions and it must have a space after the first and before the last bracket.

E.g. `[ "$var" = "expected value" ]`
and not `["$var" = "expected value"]`